# What Kafka broker metrics should be monitored if producer side ack lag is very high

Tags: apache-kafka, monitoring

Are there some broker metrics we can use to monitor Kafka broker if acknowledgment lag is very high in the producer side.

We are using datadog to monitor producer and Kafka broker side. It can be seen that the producer ack lag is more than 10 secs. However, on the broker side, I feel like only using `message.in.rate` and `kafka.net.bytes_in.rate` are not very efficient. It would be better we can have some LAG metrics in the broker side to indicate `the broker is fully loaded to acknowledge back the producer.`

Also, we only use `kafka.acks = 1` for partition leader.

I wonder does anyone has some experience about it and any advice is welcome. :) Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm guessing you're talking about "metrics" instead of matrix!

On the Producer, you have `kafka.producer:type=producer-metrics,client-id="{client-id}"`. That metric has 2 interesting attributes:

- request-latency-avg: The average request latency in ms
- request-latency-max: The maximum request latency in ms

On the broker side, there are a few metrics you want to check to investigate your issue:

- Message conversion time: Down convertion happens if the producer is using a older message format than the broker. `kafka.network:type=RequestMetrics,name=MessageConversionsTimeMs,request=Produce`
- Request total time: Total time Kafka took to process the request. `kafka.network:type=RequestMetrics,name=TotalTimeMs,request=Produce`

  In case this is high, you can check the break down metrics:

  - Time the request waits in the request queue: `kafka.network:type=RequestMetrics,name=RequestQueueTimeMs,request=Produce`
  - Time the request is processed at the leader: `kafka.network:type=RequestMetrics,name=LocalTimeMs,request=Produce`
  - Time the request waits in the response queue: `kafka.network:type=RequestMetrics,name=ResponseQueueTimeMs,request={Produce|FetchConsumer|FetchFollower}`
  - Time to send the response: `kafka.network:type=RequestMetrics,name=ResponseSendTimeMs,request=Produce`

These are all listed in the metrics recommended to monitor list in the Kafka documentation: http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#monitoring

Comment: Ha sry, changed. And yes, we have already using these attributes. Any other broker side metrics ? :)

Comment: @MickaelMaison can you please share the thresholds for setting custom alerts on these metrics ? How high or low ?